# consume https Rest API with certificate provided

Tags: rest, api, https, certificate, postman

I want to consume a https based Rest API, the corresponding team has provided me a zip with certificates, which has two directory with following files

```
truststore
 1. desktop-cacerts.jks 
 2. root-ca-g2.crt 
 3. sub-ca-g2.crt
keystore 
 1. desktop.crt 
 2. desktop.jks 
 3. root-ca-g2.crt 
 4. sub-ca-g2.crt
```

now I want to connect to the service via postman and try out, I tried to add both the jks and .crt files into Postman certificate, but I always get certificate error.
my understanding is that, I should be using keystore desktop.jks (key file) and desktop.crt to connect, which didn't work; hence I tried other combination but nothing seems to work.

can anyone help me here?

*** EDIT *** July 11, 2019 ***
it turns out the certificate provided had some slight differences, as compare to what the server/RestAPI was expecting, causing it to fail to connect.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

What is the exact error message you are getting? Does the certificate require a passphrase?
Have you looked at the guide at the [Learning Center](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/certificates/)?